# RxJs Router navigate not work from subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, router, angular10

I'm use angular 10, and have next code

```
    this.recognizer.voiceText.subscribe((text) => {
  console.log(text)
  if (text.includes('menu')) {
    this.preProcess();
    this.opened = true;
    this.postProcess();
  }
  if (text.includes('bots')) {
    this.preProcess();
    this.router.navigate(['bots']);
    this.postProcess();
  }
}, error => {

}, () => {
});
```

So I get strange logic after "this.router.navigate" - Angular just add my new page after current page.
Please see 1 picture like it's now and how it was before (2 picture)

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide your template `html` and your `...routing.module.ts` files. or provide a stackblitz (e.g.)

Comment: @DavidB. in my html I just have =     <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
=

So If I will call router.navigate by button - there is works fine
I don't know why it's failed from subscribe

Comment: this looks to me like an issue with nested <router-outlets> and not correctly defining the child routes in the routing module. (like one router outlet in app.component.html and one other in menu.component.html)

Comment: @DavidB. I don't think so. Cause it work nice, if I just call router.navigate without .subscribe()

Comment: could you still provide some more code. eg. the one that works.

Comment: do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: @DavidB. no errors, this is just add below and if I will click anything - all good

Comment: @DavidB. I tried add - change detector ref, but this behaviour still here

Answer (score 1):

I just add in constructor

```
private zone: NgZone
```

And now I use it so:

```
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['bots']);
      });
```